# Strange behaviour of g group during transition

Tags: d3.js

On click (clickme http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/BF5K2/) should move 3 shapes to new positions.  Strange things are happening to the colour, text and number of shapes.   Any ideas on how to correct this?

```
 gEnter = group.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.shape ? "rectangle" : "circle"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xRange(d.position) + "," +       yRange(d.position) + ")"; });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put just transition into function "redraw".

```
function redraw() {
   group.transition().duration(1500).ease("exp-in-out")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + xRange(d.position) + "," + yRange(d.position) + ")";
    });

}
```

Here is fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/BF5K2/2/

Comment: Thanks.  Works as expected with this update: d3.selectAll("#clickMe").on("click", function() {
 data[0].position = data[0].position + 10
 data[1].position = data[1].position + 10
 data[2].position = data[2].position + 10    
     redraw();
   
 });